# Visual Studio 22 - Asan - Failed to use and restart external symbolizer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, address-sanitizer

I am trying to setup Asan Address Sanitizer for Visual Studio 2022. I am following this guide from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170#ide-msbuild

---

I was able to (mostly, I think) follow the instructions.

But I get this warning when running my code with Asan.

```
==14676==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!
    #0 0x7ff67ec8109f in main C:\Users\Vader\source\repos\AsanTest\AsanTest\main.cpp:5
    #1 0x7ff67ec81f68 in invoke_main D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
    #2 0x7ff67ec81ebd in __scrt_common_main_seh D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
    #3 0x7ff67ec81d7d in __scrt_common_main D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:330
    #4 0x7ff67ec81fdd in mainCRTStartup D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_main.cpp:16
    #5 0x7ffe54d07613 in BaseThreadInitThunk+0x13 (C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x180017613)
    #6 0x7ffe563226b0 in RtlUserThreadStart+0x20 (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x1800526b0)
```

---

The instructions say to do 4 things:

**0. Enable Address Sanitizer** ✅
[image]

**1. Turn off edit and continue** ✅
[image: "Enable Edit and Continue Hot Reload" is turned off]

**2. Turn off /RTC1 (runtime checks)** ✅ Turned off RTC1 by right clicking on the field and deleting the value.
[image: RTC1 is turned off]

**3. Turn off /INCREMENTAL (incremental linking)** ✅
[image: Incremental linking is turned off]

---

When I do the ["Use AddressSanitizer from a developer command prompt"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170#command-prompt) I do not get this warning.

---

The test code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x[100];
int main() {
    printf("Hello!\n");
    x[100] = 5; // Boom!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't answer your question, but this does work for me.  One thing I do that might be relevant is to link with the static version of the runtime library.  Something to try, anyway.

Comment: I tried changing the runtime library to the other one but the problem persists. 
https://i.imgur.com/DemufIq.png @PaulSanders

Comment: That screenshot says DLL.  I use 'Multi Threaded Debug' (no DLL).

Comment: @PaulSanders Okay. I tried them all, nothing works. Weird thing is I do get output that says there was a buffer overflow https://hastebin.com/share/zomudonaru.yaml

Comment: Also, why it is looking for a symbolizer on the non-existent D drive?

Comment: I think that's the drive that the Microsoft dev was using when he built the CRT.  Probably not relevant, therefore.

Comment: Can you provide the  output screenshot generated by "cl XXX "  command line? And the running screenshot?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT https://hastebin.com/share/ewofezeyor.java https://hastebin.com/share/foxonowuhi.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been asked before.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Fail-to-use-and-restart-external-symbol/10222443?q=+Failed+to+use+and+restart+external+symbolizer

You can vote on issues and leave comments to bring developers attention.

The problem is related to the Visual Studio debugging environment. The same program running in visual studio will output a warning `Failed to use and restart external symbolizer`,but not on  cmd.

There is

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x86;%PATH%

ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x86
```

in Project's properties-> Debugging->Environment.
Remove the variable and the warning disappears.

Comment: I don't have that variable under `Environment`  https://i.imgur.com/fyiaG2y.png

Comment: I am using VS2022 17.6.5. The variables will be added  automatically after setting `Yes (/fsanitize=address) ` [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axbfk.png). Variables are not bolded.

Comment: Keep only PATH, get rid of ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH